# Is it possible to generate CAN message in one device and dump CAN message in another device using SocketCAN?

Tags: embedded, can-bus, socketcan

I am using SocketCAN and CANtact toolkit to send and receive CAN message. I am using two CANtact toolkits one to send CAN message and other to receive the CAN message both the CANtact toolkits are connected by DB9 female to DB9 female and the other ends are connected to the USB port of the laptop.

I used the following SocketCAN commands to first configure them

```
sudo modprobe can
sudo modprobe can_raw
sudo modprobe slcan
sudo slcand -o -s6 -t hw -S 3000000 /dev/ttyACM0 slcan0
sudo ip link set slcan0 up
```

The above commands are for the first CANtact toolkit then I connected the second CANtact toolkit and configured it with the following commands

```
sudo modprobe can
sudo modprobe can_raw
sudo modprobe slcan
sudo slcand -o -s6 -t hw -S 3000000 /dev/ttyACM1 slcan1
sudo ip link set slcan1 up
```

I performed these steps in two different terminals

In the first terminal, I gave

```
cangen -v slcan0
```

In the second terminal,I gave

```
 candump slcan1
```

I don't receive any CAN messages in terminal 2 but if i give

```
cangen -v slcan0
```

in the first terminal and

`candump slcan0`

in second terminal I am able to view the CAN messages sent

This means the CAN message is not communicated between the two CANtact toolkits How can this be resolved? Or am I committing any mistake?

[image: Connections[][1]]
[image: pin configuration]
[image: pin configuration[![][3]]][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vw3p2.jpg)

Comment: Does your hardware come with built-in termination or are you expected to add that manually?

Comment: I gave the termination by means of a jumper setting.

Comment: termination is given by the last pin configuration CTE 
schematic of the tool is available in the following link https://github.com/linklayer/cantact-hw