# How to send and receive CAN messages between two devices using CANard library?

Tags: python, can-bus

I am able to view the CAN message with a single device. I sent the frame in one terminal and received the frame in another terminal using a single CANtact tool named as slcan0. But if I use two devices again I am not able to view the message I sent the frame in one CANtact tool named as slcan0 and I tried to receive the frame in another CANtact tool named as slcan1 and connected both the CANtact toolkits with DB9 female to DB9 female cable but I am not able to view the message. How can I send and Receive frames with two different devices I have attached a screenshot for reference 
[image: refernce]
[image: connections]

Comment: How is this question different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54880371/is-it-possible-to-generate-can-message-in-one-device-and-dump-can-message-in-ano ? Also please post code as text, not as pictures.

Comment: Yes, the other question is similar to this there SocketCAN commands are used and here I am using Python program using CANard libraries.But either of the two doesn't give output required